# 2007 Nissan Armada power window fuse location

Tags: electrical, nissan, power-windows

According to the fuse block diagram, there is not a dedicated fuse for the power windows. Anyone know if the power windows are on another fuse? Front drivers side window will not go down and switch makes no noise when you hit it.

Comment: You could also gently try to help the window down the first tiny bit and see if it goes from there.  It's possible you simply have a small dead spot on your window motor.

Answer (score 3):

Look in the underhood fuse box, it may be a maxi-fuse, or a circuit breaker. However they are not fused separately so if the other windows work it's not the fuse.

The most common cause is the motor. One thing you can do is sitting in the car with the dome light on push the window button up and down and see if you notice the dome light get a little dimmer when you push the switch. If so it's defiantly the motor, other than that you will have pull the door panel off for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the stuff in the cabin of your car (power windows, radio, etc.) are commonly grouped together on the fuse labeled 'ACC'. This fuse is located in the fusebox under the hood or in a seperate fusebox located inside the cabin. Please consult your manual for the location of the fusebox(es) and a diagram of all the fuses.

However, when one window doesn't work while the others are perfectly fine I suspect there's something wrong with the button or the motor. You can use a multimeter to troubeshoot these.

Answer (score 2):

Well according to my Haynes repair manual for a Nissan Armada 2005-2010 year model the power windows are protected by fuses and a circuit breaker. The fuses are located in the fuse panel and each motor is equipped with an internal circuit breaker, this prevents one stuck window from disabling the whole system.

Answer (score 1):

Im almost certain your problem is not as intense as a failed motor and/or master switch. I suggest checking ALL your fuses (cabin and under the hood), use a test light. Change any fuse that "fails" to "light up" the test light. If none, then with the ignition off, sort of strategically "jiggle" the fusebox's main harnesses. I'm almost convinced therein lies your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Would you mind [editing](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/58278/edit) your answer to clarify what you mean by "any that 'fails'"?